# Как по нажатию на Notification открыть MainActivity и выполнить конкретный метод

Tags: android, xamarin, android-notification, xamarin.android

Мне нужно чтобы по клику на уведомление пользователь попадал на главный экран и выполнялся метод `void Out()`

Как я могу это реализовать?

Сейчас использую такой вызова уведомлений

```
var resultIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID).SetPriority(1)
                          .SetAutoCancel(true) 
                          .SetContentTitle("Уведомление") 
                          .SetNumber(1) 
                          .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon)
                          .SetContentText($"Описание"); 

var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(this);
notificationManager.Notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.Build());
```

Comment: Вам надо установить contentIntent, передав в него PendingIntent, в который надо передать Intent, в который надо что-то положить в Extras, в активити надо переопределить onNewIntent в который придет Intent. Именно в этом методе и запускайте ваш метод, если в Extras интернета пришло нужное значение

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Не могли бы вы расписать, это мое первое приложение и я еще не работал с Intent

Comment: Только если завтра смогу. С телефона дико не удобно(

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я ответ опубликовал, надеюсь вы не в обиде, что я вас немного опередил :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если [@ЮрийСПб](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/17609/%D0%AE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%A1%D0%9F%D0%B1) будет не в обиде, то я напишу ответ :) Для того чтобы открыть активность и выполнить метод вам нужно как уже было сказано в комментариях послать данные в активность о том что нужно сделать. Возьмем ваш код:

```
var resultIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
```

Суть intent в том что можно послать данные в открываемую активность. Например вы можете послать какой-то идентификатор того что нужно сделать в активности:

```
intent.putExtra("some_data", data);
```

Дальше в активности вы "ловите" данные которые пришли в методе onCreate():

```
val action = intent.getIntExtra("some_data", 0)
```

Как можно увидеть из принимающего `intent` там по-умолчанию у меня стоит 0, это например можно поставить такое число, но можно и любое другое. То есть суть данного приема в том что вы шлете например в активность число 1, и активность принимает это число 1, если ничего не шлете то будет по-умолчанию 0. Ну и в итоге, после того как вы приняли данные в активности, можно вызывать метод который вам нужно. Можно сделать через `if` или  `when`. Подробнее про передачу данных через intent можно почитать [здесь](https://android.jlelse.eu/passing-data-between-activities-using-intent-in-android-85cb097f3016).

### UPDATE

В активности которая будет принимать данные вы регистрируете данный receiver:

```
val filter = IntentFilter("identificator")
receiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
   override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
      // your action
    }
}

registerReceiver(receiver, filter)
```

и дальше для отправки делаем так:

```
val inten = Intent()
inten.action = "identificator"
inten.putExtra("some_data", 3)
context.sendBroadcast(inten)
```

это общие сведения для отправки данных через receiver. [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491631/create-notification-with-broadcastreceiver) указана информация про отправку таких данных из уведомления. Суть приблизительно одинакова, так как здесь тоже используются intent который нужно использовать в `pending intent`

Comment: Я сделал следующим образом `var resultIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            resultIntent.PutExtra("some_data", 1);
            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.Create(this);
            stackBuilder.AddNextIntent(resultIntent);
            var pendingIntent = stackBuilder.GetPendingIntent(1, 1);` Подскажите возможно ли не перезапускать MainActivity, а использовать открытый?

Comment: можно попробовать сделать через broadcast receiver в таком случае

Comment: Не могли бы вы рассказать применение подробнее

Comment: Спасибо, но я использую xamarin android. И или я неправильно адаптирую или это делается другим способом

Comment: Для понимания у меня есть MainActivity в котором есть данные от пользователя + карта, к которым и должен возвратится пользователь (их сложно запоминать и востанавливать). Поэтому я планировал что-то вроде: по нажатию на уведомление открыть приложение